# Fundamental lemma of variational calculus in beam theory

Tags: physics, calculus-of-variations

I'm following the derivation of Timoshenko beam equation on [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko_beam_theory#Quasistatic_Timoshenko_beam)

At one point we arrive at the following:

$$ \int_L \left[\left(\frac{\partial M_{xx}}{\partial x} - Q_x\right)~\delta\varphi - \left(\frac{\partial Q_{x}}{\partial x} + q\right)~\delta w\right]~\mathrm{d}L = 0 $$

where the integral is taken along the length $L$ of the beam. The moment $M_{xx}$, the shear force $Q_{x}$ and the variations on the beam angle and deflection, $\delta \varphi$ and $\delta w$, are functions of $x$.

Then:

> The governing equations for the beam are, from the fundamental theorem of variational calculus,

$$ \frac{\partial M_{xx}}{\partial x} - Q_x = 0 ~;~~ \frac{\partial Q_{x}}{\partial x} + q = 0 $$

I know the fundamental theorem/lemma of variational calculus is: If a smooth function $f(x)$ satisfies the following formula for any $h(x)$ with certain properties on the interval between $a$ and $b$, then $f(x)=0$.

$${\displaystyle \int _{a}^{b}f(x)h(x)\,\operatorname {d} x=0}$$

But how does this lemma apply in the case of the beam equation derivation? If we compare the first equation to the last, what are the functions $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ of the fundamental lemma, in the first equation? In the first equation we have **two** functions $\frac{\partial M_{xx}}{\partial x} - Q_x$ and $\frac{\partial Q_{x}}{\partial x} + q$, **both** independently found to equal zero. **So how did we just use the fundamental lemma, dealing with only one function, to the first equation that is an expression dealing with two functions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works here because you have two variations, the angle and deflection. You can generalize the fundamental lemma like so:

> If two smooth functions $f$ and $g$ satisfy $$ \int [f(x)\phi(x) + g(x)\psi(x)]~dx = 0$$ for all smooth compactly supported functions $\phi$ and $\psi$, then $f = 0$ and $g=0$.

This follows easily from the standard version of the fundamental lemma. To see that $f = 0$, since the above equation holds for any $\psi$ you are free to choose $\psi = 0$. Then we find that $f$ satisfies $$\int f(x)\phi(x)~dx = 0$$ for any $\phi$, so by the fundamental lemma we conclude that $f = 0$. Similarly if you set $\phi = 0$ you conclude that $g = 0$.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!